# PHP loaded configuration file not recognized

Tags: php, apache

I am using APache 2.4 and PHP5.6 , I installed them manually, at first when I unzipped PHP there is no configuration file, apart from that there are two php files with ini.development and ini.production, when I set path of PHP files in Apache httpd.conf and try to run phpinfo() to get the details of the php installation , the page loads, but the php configuration file values are none, as a result when I deploy the application mysqli_extensions are shown as fatal errors, here are the values that are showing none

Loaded Configuration File  (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  (none)
Additional .ini files parsed  (none)

If someone have any suggestions please let me know

Comment: Assuming this is a development environment, `cp ini.development php.ini`

Comment: Yes it is development environment @Ben Harold

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the server software, you're probably better off using a package manager like `apt-get`, `yum` or `homebrew` to install and maintain software like Apache and PHP.

That being said, the `ini.development` and `ini.production` files are references so that you can build your own `php.ini` file. To get started, just copy the appropriate file to create a default `php.ini` file  (`cp ini.development php.ini`). You can then go through the `php.ini` file and fine-tune your configuration.

You might need to `sudo apachectl restart` for changes to take effect.

Comment: Hello benharold, I did copy the content of the php ini-development content to new file named as php.ini with extension configuration settings, and I restarted the server, but it didn't work. I am running it on Windows R2 2012 Server

Comment: Oh, Windoze. Sorry, no experience whatsoever.